# codeigniter page not found on live server

Tags: codeigniter, server, live

codeigniter page not found showing but working fine in local server.

I had uploaded codeigniter file of one basic simple page on live server but there it is showing no page found and same file it is working on local server.

In that I had

```
mine.php ---- controller
index.php --- view
```

I loaded in routes default controller - mine in config base url- domain.com removed index.php also

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

can I know please why it is showing page not found, might be some routing issue but I had loaded default controller also.  Please help out on this

Comment: what version of ci are you using? and what does your config file look like?

Comment: In your `application > controllers >  mine.php` rename it to `Mine.php` and same goes for class. Also you don't have to use the index.php for your view you can create you own explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: but controller name is in capital letter Mine and controller file name is mine.php, if both will be in capital letter it will be right or i should make controller name in small letter.

Comment: here my controller code mine.php -------------                                       <?php
class Mine extends MY_Controller{
public function index()
 {
$this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->view('index');
 }
}                                                                                                           
 and here index.php in view----------------                                        <html>
<head>
  <title>first page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <h3>hii i launched</h3>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

First of all start error logging properly so you can see the actuall error.

Change your file name's first letter capital. This is mendetory as explained here [ci3 manual - controllers](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html). It says class name as well as file name must start with capital. ( If your Dev machine is windows  then it will not show errors if you don't follow this rule. Because window's file system is case insensitive. But on your server it is linux.so it will show error)

If you still  don't get it working then try access the url  with index.php in it. Temporaryly disable .htaccess .If you get it working then may be  you have problem in . htaccess. Try the following link to properly remove index.php from your url. [Expression engine forum](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html)  .This htaccess worked for me on all different server I have used.

Answer (score 0):

add this in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```